# Moving files between remote sites - Avoid local buffering

Tags: java, zero-copy

I need to move two files (from remote host A to remote host B) using a Java application in a third host (my local host).

I was wondering if there is any chance of getting the data transferred directly from host A to host B without the data being previously transferred to my local host buffer. This is because connection between remote sites is much faster than connection from my local computer to any of those hosts.

If I use Java NIO channels to transfer the data, will the data be transferred directly from channel (host) A to channel (host) B? It's not clear to me that this is possible.

I know it could be done by creating a remote application in any of the remote sites and send a webservice or RMI request from my local machine to copy the files but I'd like to avoid this.

It's not possible to get a FTP server installed in any of the servers either

Thanks

Comment: any possibility of having ssh installed for the servers?

Comment: 'Local buffering' doesn't have anything do with it. You don't want the data to *traverse a network path to the host your code is running on,* which means you're planning to run the code in the wrong host. I believe FTP has a facility for copying between two remote hosts directly, but I've never used it and I'm unaware how widely it is supported.

Comment: @EJP you are right. I finally used a JMS approach copying locally in the host. See my own accepted answer